# Error in converting date time to 24 hour format

Tags: r, datetime

I have the following dataframe and am trying to calculate the difference in minutes between dates in vectors and store it into a new one.

```
Reportnumber              OpenedDate
       00001    22/1/2016 5:52:12 PM
       00002    20/1/2016 4:15:06 PM
       00003    18/1/2016 1:09:46 PM
       00004   15/1/2016 10:47:40 AM
       00005   15/1/2016 10:32:37 AM
       00006    14/1/2016 2:13:48 PM
       00007   14/1/2016 11:12:29 AM
       00008   14/1/2016 10:17:30 AM 
       00009    12/1/2016 2:25:03 PM
```

Before using `difftime` to get the difference, I'm trying to convert the time to a 24 hour format and strip AM/PM, I'm doing the following:

```
dataset$convertedDate <- as.POSIXct('dataset$OpenedDate', format="%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%s")
```

I don't get an error in the console but the `dataset$convertedDate` vector isn't updated.

Is this the right way to approach the problem?

Comment: What format are your `OpenedDate` and `ClosedDate` columns?

Comment: `dput()`

`structure(c(9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("12/01/2016 2:25:03 PM", 
"14/01/2016 10:17:30 AM", "14/01/2016 11:12:29 AM", "14/01/2016 2:13:48 PM", 
"15/01/2016 10:32:37 AM", "15/01/2016 10:47:40 AM", "18/01/2016 1:09:46 PM", 
"20/01/2016 4:15:06 PM", "22/01/2016 5:52:12 PM"), class = "factor")`

Comment: It is for `OpenedDate`, though `dput()` sorts them dirrerently. But it shouldn't be a problem, no?

Comment: You have a simple typo in your call to `as.POSIXct()`.  You are passing in a string called `'dataset$OpenedDate'`.  You are _not_ passing in the column from your data frame.  Please fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Get ready for a facepalm.

Look closely at the call you are making:

```
dataset$convertedDate <- as.POSIXct('dataset$OpenedDate', format="%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%s")
```

You are passing in `'dataset$OpenedDate'` instead of `dataset$OpenedDate`.  In other words, you are actually passing in a text string to `as.POSIXct()`!  I verified that passing in a string to `as.POSIXct()` indeed returns `NA`, which is what you are seeing.

You were also missing a format parameter for `PM` (`%p`).  Try the following, which assumes that the timezone is `UTC` (which you can change to fit your needs):

```
as.POSIXct(df$OpenedDate, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "2016-01-22 17:52:12 UTC" "2016-01-20 16:15:06 UTC"
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Reportnumber=c('00001', '00002'),
                 OpenedDate=c('22/1/2016 5:52:12 PM', '20/1/2016 4:15:06 PM'),
                 ClosedDate=c('25/1/2016 1:35:05 PM', '20/1/2016 4:30:06 PM'))
```

Comment: I'm getting:

`> as.POSIXct('dataset$OpenedDate', format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
[1] NA`

Comment: Try running `Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")` and then try again

Comment: After having recovered from the facepalm, it worked, as it should. Many thanks:

`> as.POSIXlt(dataset$OpenedDate, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC") 

[1] "2016-01-22 17:52:12 UTC" "2016-01-20 16:15:06 UTC" "2016-01-18 13:09:46 UTC" "2016-01-15 10:47:40 UTC"
[5] "2016-01-15 10:32:37 UTC" "2016-01-14 14:13:48 UTC" "2016-01-14 11:12:29 UTC" "2016-01-14 10:17:30 UTC"
[9] "2016-01-12 14:25:03 UTC"`

(Alslo for the record: `> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C") [1] "C"`)